# email verification in laravel for multi auth

Tags: laravel, authentication

```
Auth::routes(['verify'=>true]);
```

how to add above verify tag in following routes?

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
Route::get('/dashboard','AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard')->middleware('guest:a');
Route::get('/logout','Admin\LoginController@logout');
Route::get('/','Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/','Admin\LoginController@login');

Route::post('/password/email','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('admin.password.email');
Route::get('/password/reset','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('admin.password.update');
Route::post('password/reset','Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset');
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}','Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');
Route::get('/register','Admin\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('admin.register');
Route::post('/register','Admin\RegisterController@register')->name('admin.register');});
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want another authentication system for admin with email verification

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information and explain in more detail, but I think you are verifying your user through an email. So

`Auth::routes(['verify'=>true]);`

Just means if the user is currently authentificated.

If you want to make your routes only accessible for authenticated users you have two options of how to accomplish this:

The first option is to add the auth middleware in your controller's constructor like this:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    ...
```

And your second option which is prefer is to add the middleware in your routes file and include the routes which shall only ne accessible in that group like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   Route::get('/test','Admin\TestController@test');
   ...
```

Hope that helps you, again I am not 100% sure what you mean so you should probably explain your question further.

Comment: i want to add verification controller on my admin module similar to default auth scanfolding provided by laravel